# Communicate with multiple SQL Servers at all time

Tags: sql-server, caching

I am looking for a way to communicate with multiple database-servers at all times.

How I would want it to work: a connection is established from a program to a server or any other program that receives normal database-calls.

1. If it is a select statement only the server program/server should select the database-server with least traffic that is online.
2. Handle that the SQL Server goes offline and can handle all updates and creations that has been made when that server were offline and update the server with that data when it comes online again (or sync the databases).

Is there any good solutions for this, or any programs that can handle this type of request?

Comment: I think you want to learn about database replication and mirroring.

Comment: Can you include the framework you are using, it will help get more answers.

Comment: depending on if you are using `mssql`, `mysql`, `oracle`, something on AWS etc. there are a lot of solutions for this, and entire careers are built around solving it :)

Answer (score 0):

As already proposed by others, looking at mirroring and replication might lead to a better overall solution.

In order to solve this specific issue I would recommend to put a LoadBalancer in front of the DBs while using a dedicated connection string in your code only for select statements. That connection string should point to the LoadBalancer. The LoadBalancer should have the LEAST CONNECTION principle applied.